# Snippet-Editor javascript error in popup window if editing a Q w/ pending edit

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, editor, popup

While editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793706/centering-image-on-full-page-with-css) on StackOverflow, I was attempting to quickly move the provided code sample into the `Code-Snippet` wysiwyg editor so that the sample could be run and previewed on the page.  The question already had a pending edit (which was an edit of the questions associated tags) so when I attempted to edit as well, I believe the fact that it had a pending edit resulted in it loading in a popup window and displaying a review prompt.

[image]

I selected the optino `Improve the edit` and cut out the code block that was provided.  Selected the toolbar button for the `snippet-editor` and pasted the code into the next window.  The `Tidy` and `Run` buttons within the editor worked fine, but the 'Insert into Post' was unresponsive.  I also noticed that there was a duplicate of the snippet-editor button visible in the toolbar..  I attempted the same actions by attempting to start the process from each of them since there were two.. checking to see if perhaps only the duplicate copy was causing the error.

Both attempts produced identical results.  Console reported a javascript error which I've posted below..

### [image]

Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'save'
    of undefinedsnippet - javascript.en.js ? v = 1d51257a8f1d : 
1(anonymous function) jquery.min.js: 
    3 f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js: 
    3 h.handle.ijquery.min.js:
    3 f.event.triggerjquery.min.js:
3(anonymous function) jquery.min.js: 
    2 e.extend.eachjquery.min.js: 
    2 e.fn.e.eachjquery.min.js: 
    3 f.fn.extend.triggerjquery.min.js: 
    3 f.fn.(anonymous function) snippet - javascript.en.js ? v = 1d51257a8f1d : 
1(anonymous function) jquery.min.js: 
    3 f.event.dispatchjquery.min.js: 
    3 h.handle.i
```

---

- **Model Name:** `MacBook Pro, 15-inch/Mid-2014`
- **Processor Name:** `Intel Core i7`
- **Processor Speed:** `2.5 GHz`
- **Operating System:** `OS X Yosemite v10.10.1`
- **Browser:** `Google Chrome v39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)`

Comment: Thats possibly  because you are improving it from popup, not the fact it has a pending edit.

Comment: reproduced, on it